# Brackets Like Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Hellow guys am a newbie in javascript .I have seen some code like this ..

```
function f() {

    var model = this.model.attributes;

    var data = {
        path: Config.baseUrl,
        lang: url.segment(1),
        id: model['id'],
        date: model['date'],
        views: model['views'],
        author: model['author'],
        authorName: model['authorName'],
        question: model['question'],
        answer: model['answer'],
        rate: model['rate'],
        _ : _,
        S: S,
        moment: moment
    };
```

I just need to know `model['id']` `model['views']` etc etc ..i just need to know the use of id,date,views author here .In php its like array and key but is it the same concept in jaavascript too ..Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks .:)

Comment: model['date'] is like writing model.date : it's written either object['property'] or object.property

Comment: Its called [__Bracket notation__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With  `views: model['views'],`

You declare views equal to the views attribute of the model element.

And so on with the others

Comment: didnt get ?..so is model a fixed varibale term here ?

Comment: Yes model is somewhere outside the func. In the function is a fixed variable

Comment: so can we use any other term instead of model for this same purpose ?

Comment: You can use any term you want as soon as it is declared somewhere outside the function. It is like other variables

Answer (score 0):

The use of `this` is one thing to watch out for. The `model` variable inside `f` is being assigned to a `model` property outside the function. So look for `model` in the outer object to figure out where that stuff is coming from.

Comment: is model a fixed term ?..i just need to know that ...

Comment: No, `this` is a moving target in javascript. You have to study the hierarchy of objects to find out where it is coming from.

Comment: can you give me a link to study all these ?..can we use any other tem insted of model for this purpose ..